# Interface inheritance in classes

Tags: c#

I have,

```
interface IService
{
}
interface IProductService
{
}
class Service : IService
{
}
class ProductService : IProductService
{
}
```

Should ProductService also inherit from Service class. What I am looking is that put the general methods in IService/Service class and specific things in IProductService/ProductService.

The problem is that if I inherit `ProductService : IProductService` then I need to implement all methods of IService which are already available in Service class.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure I did understand what's the question...

Comment: Additionally, consider `interface IProductService : IService`

Comment: why can't you inherit from service and Iproductservice in the productservice class ?

Comment: Without knowing what's contained in these classes and interfaces, who knows?!

Comment: The problem is that if I inherit `ProductService : IProductService` then you need to implement all methods of IService which are already available in Service class.

Comment: @RowlandShaw, Thanks. But what about `ProductService`. Should It inherit form Service class or not?

Comment: @user960567 There's no single correct answer, and to a certain extent, it's up to the implementor - `Service` implements `IService` but who's to say whether its implementation is better than any other concrete class implementing that interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all depends on whether you want to share implementation using inheritance of the implementing classes, and whether the more specialized interfaces are always extending the base interfaces. Without knowing what the interfaces and implementations contain it is hard to say. Basically, there are a number of permutations for how to define the interfaces and make the implementation. If you provide some more information it will be easier to select the proper one.

With implementation inheritance + interface inheritance

```
interface IService { }
interface IProductService : IService { }
abstract class Service : IService { }     
class ProductService : Service, IProductService { }
```

With implementation inheritance, separate interfaces

```
interface IService { }
interface IProductService { }
abstract class Service : IService { }
class ProductService : Service, IProductService { }
```

With interface inheritance only

```
interface IService { }
interface IProductService : IService { }
class Service : IService { }
class ProductService : IProductServicde { }
```

Without inheritance:

```
interface IService { }
interface IProductService { }
class Service : IService  {  }
class ProductService : IService, IProductService { }
```

Comment: The problem is that if I inherit `ProductService : IProductService` then I need to implement all methods of IService which are already available in Service class.

Comment: @user960567 *Why* is that a problem?

Comment: If you *want* to share implementation between Service and ProductService then you should simply pick one of the first two, where the Service class is a base class that contains the shared methods.

If you *don't* then you pick one of the bottom two.

Answer (score 1):

A `IProductService` is a more specialized inteface than `IProduct`?
So you could add specialized methods to the `IProductService`:

```
interface IService { }

interface IProductService : IService { }
```

And then declare your `Service` and `ProductService` classes as implementation on the two interfaces.

**Edit**

If you need to specialize the `ProductService` from the `Service` class, you can always use multiple inheritence:

```
class Service : IService { }

class ProductService : Service, IProductService { }
```

Comment: The problem is that if I inherit ProductService : IProductService then I need to implement all methods of IService which are already available in Service class.